# Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: jquery, socket, websocket

Estou tentando aplicar uma conexão com websockets, porém ao executar, dá o seguinte erro:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Já tentei as portas, 80, 9000, 12345, etc., mas o erro persiste.

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
    var callbacks = {};
    var ws_url = url;
    var conn;

    this.bind = function(event_name, callback)
    {
        callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
        callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
        return this;
    };

    this.send = function(event_name, event_data)
    {
        this.conn.send( event_data );
        return this;
    };

    this.connect = function() 
    {
        if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
        this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
        else
        this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

        this.conn.onmessage = function(evt)
        {
            dispatch('message', evt.data);
        };

        this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
        this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
    };

    this.disconnect = function()
    {
        this.conn.close();
    };

    var dispatch = function(event_name, message)
    {
        if(message == null || message == "")
            {
            }
            else
            {
                var JSONdata    = JSON.parse(message); 
                switch(JSONdata[0].actualizacion)
                {
                    case '1':
                    actualiza_mensaje(message);
                    break;
                    case '2':
                    actualiza_solicitud(message);
                    break;

                }
            }
    }
};

var Server;
function send( text ) 
{
    Server.send( 'message', text );
}
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://ip_do_servidor:80');
    Server.bind('open', function()
    {
    });
    Server.bind('close', function( data ) 
    {
    });
    Server.bind('message', function( payload ) 
    {
    });
    Server.connect();
});



function actualiza_mensaje(message)
{
    var JSONdata    = JSON.parse(message); 
                var tipo = JSONdata[0].tipo;
                var mensaje = JSONdata[0].mensaje;
                var fecha = JSONdata[0].fecha;

                var contenidoDiv  = $("#"+tipo).html();
                var mensajehtml   = fecha+' : '+mensaje;

                $("#"+tipo).html(contenidoDiv+'0000111'+mensajehtml);
}
function actualiza_solicitud()
{
    alert("tipo de envio 2");
}
```

Servidor

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require 'classes/class.PHPWebSocket.php';

function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) 
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }

    if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
        $Server->wsSend($clientID, "");
    else
        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
                $Server->wsSend($id,$message);
}
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "" );

    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "");
}

function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "" );

    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "");
}

$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');

$Server->wsStartServer('ip_do_servidor',80);

?>
```

Comment: Tens algum serviço de websockets a correr nessas portas?

Comment: Perdão miguel. Essa é a primeira vez que trabalho com websockets. Não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Ah sim. Se tem outro serviço. Não sei te informar, pois o nosso servidor é remoto.

Comment: O erro sofreu timeout (tempo de requisicao esgotado). O Miguel perguntou se o serviço está rodando nessa porta, ou se apenas está rodando. Voce consegue testar usando um telnet. Ex: `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`, se fechar a conexão é porque tem algum serviço ouvindo ali..

Comment: Fox acho que devias começar por qualquer coisa como isto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHbCkikFfDE . O que tu tens parece-me que é só o lado cliente, tens de ter um serviço de websockets a correr neste caso no 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: Olá Lucas. Certo. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Olá Miguel. Atualizei meu post com o lado servidor. Entrei em contato com o servidor e eles informaram que a porta é 80, porém o erro que dá no Chrome é: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://ip_do_servidor/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200` e no Firefox: `O Firefox não conseguiu estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor ws://ip_do_servidor/.`

Comment: Fox, `$Server->wsStartServer('ip_do_servidor',80);` coloca o ip correto. Mas não vai dar para ser a 80 com certeza, coloca qualquer coisa como 8080

Comment: Olá Miguel. O ip foi colocado dessa forma propositalmente, pois é do servidor do cliente e  prefiro manter no anonimato, combinado?